# Apply conditional formatting for entire sheet based on the lookup values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, gs-vlookup

I have 2 sheets. The first one has 2 columns:

- A:A - sequential numbers from 1 to 100
- B:B - 1-5 value for each number in A

Another sheet has matrix 10x10 from 1 to 100 where I would like to make conditional formatting by defining by the value from `Sheet1!B`. For example on the `Sheet2` there will be number `55`. Then I need to go Sheet1, find value 55 in column A and then based on the value in column B decide what formatting to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:B"), 2, 0)=5
```

[image: 0]

Comment: if the values that are currently in B column would be in Z column, would it be Sheet2!A:Z?

Comment: yes, but formula would be then: `=VLOOKUP(D2, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:Z"), 26, 0)=5`